# Selenium Crashing when I use my chrome profile | how to add chrome profile to selenium instance?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=options)

driver.get("google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
```

Trying to see if I can have selenium open up an instance of chrome using one of my chrome profiles. That way I don't have to have my logins in clear text. Above is my original code ^^^ Thank you!

I tried adding my profile path like so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Profile 1")
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\F\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\\")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                          options=options)

driver.get("google.com")
driver.maximize_window()
```

The chrome instance will launch using the correct profile, however, it will crash with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\main.py", line 11, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 106, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 288, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 381, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\F\Documents\ShippingBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00FAACD3+2075859]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F3EE61+1633889]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E3B7BD+571325]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E5AA93+699027]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E56BE9+682985]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8DBD3+908243]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E8D6AA+906922]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E87136+880950]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E5FEFD+720637]
    Ordinal0 [0x00E60F3F+724799]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0125EED2+2769538]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01250D95+2711877]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0103A03A+521194]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x01038DA0+516432]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F4682C+1665068]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F4B128+1683752]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F4B215+1683989]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F56484+1729668]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75CCFEF9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B17BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77B17B8E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Before executing the above code, close all the chrome browser windows and try.

Comment: @AbiSaran yes that worked! Can you please explain why I have to close all the browsers? Is there a way to get around this? Thank you!

Comment: @AbiSaran That must be a bug hey coz surely that cant be how its supposed to work. I know years back this worked just fine whether chrome was open or not